# Javascript runtime add js / css, how to get progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to runtime add css and javascripts. I want to be sure they are loaded before going further but cannot find how I can check the dynamic loading progress of an added file.

This is my loading script. Is there some basic js function I'm missing or maybe something with jQuery?

```
function loadFileRuntime(filename){

    "use strict";

    var fileType;
    var fileRef;
    var lastIndex = filename.indexOf("?");
    if(lastIndex===0) {
        fileType = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }else{
        fileType = filename.substring( filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1, lastIndex );
    }


    switch(fileType){

        case "js":
            fileRef = document.createElement('script');
            fileRef.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileRef.setAttribute("src", filename);
            break;

        case "css":
            fileRef = document.createElement("link");
            fileRef.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileRef.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileRef.setAttribute("href", filename);
            break;
    }

    if (typeof fileRef !== "undefined"){
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
    }

}
```

Comment: *Why* are you doing this is my first question? There are alternatives.

Comment: For JS files jQuery has a method here which can be use to execute a callback when the file is loaded https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ . CSS are generally more work as the file loaded doesn't mean it is computed yet. But a simple way would be to load the content via AJAX and insert it as a style tag which would give you another callback. There are also libraries out there designed for this task some may be found here http://microjs.com/#load